# Can I use filter on a formula within a postgres statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a weird query where I am aggregating some results and others I need to do formulas on but for the formulas I need to filter the results, but it's not working for me.

Here's my statement:

```
((table.grossprofit - table.totalrevenue) FILTER (WHERE lower(table.ticker) = 'aapl.us') as numeric)  AS company_cogs
```

I get :

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "FILTER"
```

What is the best way to do formulas while also filtering using a where statement?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `Filter` is used with aggregation or window functions.

Comment: The larger query gets alot more data(all companies in my case), but certain columns I want them filtered for specific companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aggregating, then presumably you have an aggregation function.  Then the syntax would look like:

```
sum(table.grossprofit - table.totalrevenue) FILTER (
    WHERE lower(table.ticker) = 'aapl.us') AS company_cogs
```

Answer (score 2):

Filter using with aggregation function. I don't see any aggregation function here.
see [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-expressions.html)

```
aggregate_name ( * ) [ FILTER ( WHERE filter_clause ) ]
```

example:

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS unfiltered,
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE i < 5) AS filtered
FROM generate_series(1,10) AS s(i);
 unfiltered | filtered
------------+----------
         10 |        4
(1 row)
```